# use rails button in form as link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a table with sliders (part of a form) in one column and a button (link to other page)

```
<button onclick="location.href='/main';">
   <i class="icon icon-078-settings icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Instead of opening the page, the button just submits the form. Any way I can fix this without breaking the table or the form?

Comment: You should have *anchor tags* instead of a *button*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just use anchor tag

```
<a href='/main'>
  <i class="icon icon-078-settings icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

or

```
# If you are using erb
<%= link_to '/main' do %>
  <i class="icon icon-078-settings icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
<a href='/main' class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon icon-078-settings icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

If you used bootstrap css then you can add classes `btn` and `btn-paimary` which makes button.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of opening the page, the button just submits the form.

Yes! Buttons are meant to *perform actions that effects on front-end or back-end*, they are *not meant for navigation*. You should use *links(a.k.a anchors)* to perform navigation.

```
<a href='/main'>
  <i class="icon icon-078-settings icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```